# Eclipse Oxygen, How to close this Tab/Directory/...?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I accidentally opened this hierarchy/directory, or whatever tab in my eclipse oxygen... It is slowing down my eclipse because whenever I click something it updates and shows the information of that method/variable... How can I close it? It is enclosed by the red rectangle in the picture below. I tried to google it, but it is very hard to find useful results when I don't even know what this is called... Many thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called breadcrumb.

There's a button in the global toolbar, called `Toogle Breadcrumb`.

In my eclipse there's no keybinding for it, but you can configure this via `Window` -> `Preference` -> `General` -> `Keys`. The corresponding command is called `Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb`.

Comment: After seeing your answer, a simple google solved my problem. I feel  relieved now that it's gone... Thank you so much!